# Sinhala Unicode rendering issues in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, unicode

When I use Sinhala Unicode word "ප්‍රවාහන" in JLabel it renders as "ප්රවාහන".

I think is problem in ZWJ character. Any ideas how to fix it?

I'm using Java 7 in Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

There is a ZERO WIDTH JOINER (U+200D) in the first string. Try removing them:

```
new JLabel(s.replace("\u200D", ""));
```